# Upload Form Throws Same Error Twice

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

I'm trying to create an upload form with CodeIgniter to give users the possibility to change their profile picture. In my Controller is the following lines of code:

```
if(!$this->upload->do_upload() && empty($_FILES['userfile'])) {
    $data['upload'] = "0";
    $this->load->view('editpicture', $data);
} elseif (!$this->upload->do_upload() && !empty($_FILES['userfile'])) {
    $data['upload'] = "0";
    $data['attempt'] = "1";
    $data['error'] = $this->upload->display_errors();
    $this->load->view('editpicture', $data);        
} else {
    $upload_data = $this->upload->data();
    ....
```

Everything works fine except when I get an error. The view shows the same error twice:

> You did not select a file to upload.
> You did not select a file to upload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
if(!$this->upload->do_upload()) {
    if (empty($_FILES['userfile'])) {
        $data['upload'] = "0";
        $this->load->view('editpicture', $data);
    } else {
        $data['upload'] = "0";
        $data['attempt'] = "1";
        $data['error'] = $this->upload->display_errors();
        $this->load->view('editpicture', $data);       
    }
} else {
    $upload_data = $this->upload->data();
    ....
```

The reason why it is happening is you are running `$this->upload->do_upload()` twice. The first condition runs it to see if it is `FALSE` and then checks `$_FILES` if it is empty to run the block of code.

Well if `$this->upload->do_upload()` is TRUE and `$_FILES` is empty then it will run, but if `$_FILES` is not empty it will run next condition where you run `$this->upload->do_upload()` again in the condition. The function is being executed in the `if()` twice then. Conditional checks run left to right.

Comment: And that, my fiend, was the solution! Thank you